# How to find list of open ports in any given ip without using common scanning tools

Tags: network-scanners

Suppose I want to port scan my network. Normally I'll use a tool like nmap or nessus.

What if we don't have any tool to perform a Port Scan - how can we find open ports?

Comment: No tools at all? Is telnet considered a tool? How about Windows? I think you need to better explain.

Comment: no, i don't have any automated tool to run port scan. I clarify again, i can not run any port scanner. telnet and windows are fine.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for ["online port scanner"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q="online+port+scanner")? Just saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet to every possible port. See if you get a response back. If you know the protocol typically associated with the port you can manually send some commands and see what responses you get back.

For example you could telnet to port 80 on the target device and send a get request. See what comes back.

Comment: you mean to say like,
>telnet 192.168.1.1 80
So i need to do it for every suspected port??

Comment: @shekharsuman yes